# Using simple Math in SLD file on Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, sld

Is it possible to use simple Math in an SLD file on Geoserver? Suppose I want to read a text size property from a database and multiply its value, how can I do this?

```
<sld:TextSymbolizer>
    ...
    <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">
        <ogc:PropertyName>text_size</ogc:PropertyName> * 2.1
    </sld:CssParameter>
    ...
</sld:TextSymbolizer>
```

This simple approach obviously doesn't work, so I thought there must be some way to achieve this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the math functions ogc:Mul ogc:Div ogc:Add & ogc:Sub to do simple maths on properties.

So your example would become:

```
<sld:CssParameter name="font-size">
    <ogc:Mul>
       <ogc:PropertyName>text_size</ogc:PropertyName>
       <ogc:Literal>2.5</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Mul>
</sld:CssParameter>
```

The only issue is that technically the SLD specification may not allow you to use a function in a CssParameter. However GeoServer is much more forgiving and will allow it.

If you ever need more complex functions see the [reference page](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html).

Comment: works like a charm

Comment: I found that `<ogc:Mult>` did not work for me, but `<ogc:Mul>` did.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware GeoServer cannot do any math embedded into the SLD.
You can however create a rule in the SLD that can read `<ogc:PropertyName>text_size</ogc:PropertyName>` with a filter, and define your own text size.
The **[GeoServer SLD Cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/index.html)** has some **[examples](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/points.html#attribute-based-point)** of using `<ogc:Filter>`

Comment: Seems like this is now working. Please check with versions 2.12.1 and up.