# Rotating sld with expression?

Tags: sld, expression

I'm trying to rotate an arrow based on an attribute but the arrow is off by 90 degrees.

Is there a method for doing a mathematical expression on the attribute within the sld?

I've gone over [the docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html) and [this thread](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/SLD-Rotate-a-symbol-basen-on-a-expression-with-geom-and-a-constant-td4670585.html) but have not had any luck.  It so far everything I have found pertains to arrows on lines and not arrows alone

this is how Im currently rotating

```
 <se:PointSymbolizer>
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:Mark>
                <se:WellKnownName>arrow</se:WellKnownName>
                <se:Fill>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#236de5</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Fill>
                <se:Stroke>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000000</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>
              </se:Mark>
              <se:Size>30</se:Size>
             <se:Rotation>
                <ogc:PropertyName>heading</ogc:PropertyName>
            </se:Rotation>
            </se:Graphic>
            </se:PointSymbolizer>
```

After reviewing [Using simple Math in SLD file on Geoserver?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131002) along with reading the geoserver documentation again it is still unclear on where in the function you choose your operator.  In my case I would like to use addition.  The above question is for multiplication. I would be multiplying by 90 not adding 90, the documentation doe not have comparative examples of mathematical functions being used.  I do not see in the documentation where `<ogc:Mul>` is described. I can assume that `<ogc:Add>` would work but where is this supported with documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the following:

```
<se:Rotation>
    <ogc:Add>
        <ogc:PropertyName>ROTATION</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>90</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Add>
</se:Rotation>
```

See here for the documentation on math operators: [link](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/filter_reference.html#arithmetic-operators).  I grant that the documentation could do with an example or two.