# Removing Trailing Zeros in Geoserver SLD

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have maps from a PostGIS datastore in Geoserver. The map is styled using SLD created dynamically from my web apps. The problem is that sometimes, the map has float-type attribute data.

The label actually renders correctly using `<TextSymbolizer>`, but with a trailing zeros. e.g 0.850000000000. What I want is that it should render 0.85 instead of 0.850000000000.

Is there any way I can do that using the SLD?

I'm using Geoserver 2.6.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good question. The answer at [Using simple Math in SLD file on Geoserver?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/131111/3112) may help here.

You could try something like this:

```
<Label>
  <ogc:Div>
    <ogc:Function name="Round">
      <ogc:Mul>
        <ogc:PropertyName>field_name</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>
      </ogc:Mul>
    </ogc:Function>
    <ogc:Literal>100</ogc:Literal>    
  </ogc:Div>
</Label>
```

This multiplies the value of `field_name` by 100 (in the `Mul` section), rounds it to an integer (the `"Round"` function), then divides the result by 100 (the `Div` section).

You may need to experiment with the parameters but hopefully this approach will work for you.

Comment: I'll leave this here, but you should probably use Ian's suggestion instead as it's a lot simpler

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem. I omit the 'Round' function btw. Just by multiply it by 100 and divide it by 100 solves my problem. Ian's suggestions also works great only if I have a definite number of digits, while in this situation I just want to remove only the trailing zeros.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `numberFormat` [function](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#parsing-and-formatting-functions). This allows you to specify how many digits you want after the decimal point.

Here is an example from [MASS-GIS](https://wiki.state.ma.us/display/massgis/GeoServer+-+SLD+-+numberFormat+Function):

```
    <TextSymbolizer>
        <Label>
          <Function name="numberFormat">
            <Literal>#</Literal>
            <PropertyName xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">CONTOUR_FT</PropertyName>
          </Function>
        </Label>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem I found when using your solution is just that I have no definite number of digits. It can be #.## , #.### , and so on because I just need to remove just the trailing 0. So I prefer Stephen's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `strReplace` from the [string functions](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#string-functions) which may be better than a divide and multiply. So something like

```
   <Label>
      <Function name="strReplace">
        <PropertyName xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">CONTOUR_FT</PropertyName>
        <Literal>0+$</Literal>
        <Literal></Literal>
        <Literal>false</Literal>
      </Function>
    </Label>
```

This is just a wrapper around the [Java regexp methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html) so it is pretty powerful if you need.