# Rounding values of a raster dataset in a GetFeatureInfo response

Tags: raster, geoserver, sld, getfeatureinfo

Is there a way to round decimals of floating values for a GetFeatureInfo request from a raster (geotiff) in Geoserver? I would like to round up values to 2 decimals instead of 15. Is this something I have to do in the SLD? I generated a SLD from QGIS which now looks something like this:

```
            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                  <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:RasterSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Geometry>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>grid</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </sld:Geometry>
                        <sld:ColorMap type="intervals">                                
                            <sld:ColorMapEntry color="#4575B4" label="4,0 - 4,5" opacity="1.0" quantity="4.5"/>                                
                        </sld:ColorMap>
                    </sld:RasterSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
```

I saw a similar question asked here: [Removing Trailing Zeros in Geoserver SLD](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/249659/removing-trailing-zeros-in-geoserver-sld) but I couldn't figure out how and where to implement this part:

```
<Function name="numberFormat">
   <Literal>#.##</Literal>                
</Function>
```

Usually I do rounding in PostGIS for vector data, but I am not sure how to do it with GeoTiffs.

Comment: where do you want the rounding to occur? it isn't a normal thing to do for rasters

Comment: After the second decimal. So for instance 1.920000076293945 becomes 1.92

Comment: I meant where abouts in your clients view do you want a rounded number - the legend should be using the label from your color map and I can't think where else a raster displays a number

Comment: The legend shows the rounded numbers fine, but the pop-up the user gets when clicking on the map is a direct getfeatureinfo request with the value from the raster. This shows the 15 decimal digit number, but here I would like to show only the rounded number.

Comment: This isn't an SLD operation, this will be something to do the GetFeatureInfo templating, which uses Freemarker