# Geoserver GetLegendGraphic throws an error

Tags: geoserver, legend, getlegendgraphic

I get the following error in my Geoserver

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for Filter: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find function Add
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SLDHandler.parse11(SLDHandler.java:209)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SLDHandler.parse(SLDHandler.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerDataDirectory.parsedSld(GeoServerDataDirectory.java:721)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerDataDirectory.parsedStyle(GeoServerDataDirectory.java:734)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.createStyle(ResourcePool.java:2209)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getStyle(ResourcePool.java:2189)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.StyleInfoImpl.getStyle(StyleInfoImpl.java:131)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor278.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:144)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.getStyle(Unknown Source)
    ... 132 more
```

Here is the full log:

```
13 Nov 12:39:30 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.FeatureCountProcessor.preProcessRules(FeatureCountProcessor.java:224)
    at org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.updateRuleTitles(BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.java:553)
    at org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.buildLegendGraphic(BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.java:216)
    at org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.buildLegendGraphic(BufferedImageLegendGraphicBuilder.java:77)
    at org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.PNGLegendOutputFormat.produceLegendGraphic(PNGLegendOutputFormat.java:41)
    at org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.PNGLegendOutputFormat.produceLegendGraphic(PNGLegendOutputFormat.java:21)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetLegendGraphic.run(GetLegendGraphic.java:46)
    at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getLegendGraphic(DefaultWebMapService.java:276)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor461.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:29)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy71.getLegendGraphic(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3250.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:867)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1072)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.ows.HTTPHeadersCollector.doFilter(HTTPHeadersCollector.java:48)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.HTTPMethodFilter.doFilter(HTTPMethodFilter.java:36)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:194)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:70)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:39)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:337)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilterInternal(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:375)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.getStyle(Unknown Source)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.getDefaultStyle(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:1044)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.processLayersStyles(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:655)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.GetMapKvpRequestReader.read(GetMapKvpRequestReader.java:460)
    at org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.FeatureCountProcessor.parseAssociatedGetMap(FeatureCountProcessor.java:332)
    at org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.FeatureCountProcessor.preProcessRules(FeatureCountProcessor.java:215)
    ... 122 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor278.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.LocalWorkspaceCatalog$NameDequalifyingProxy.invoke(LocalWorkspaceCatalog.java:486)
    ... 128 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for Filter: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find function Add
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SLDHandler.parse11(SLDHandler.java:209)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SLDHandler.parse(SLDHandler.java:162)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerDataDirectory.parsedSld(GeoServerDataDirectory.java:721)
    at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerDataDirectory.parsedStyle(GeoServerDataDirectory.java:734)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.createStyle(ResourcePool.java:2209)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.ResourcePool.getStyle(ResourcePool.java:2189)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.StyleInfoImpl.getStyle(StyleInfoImpl.java:131)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor278.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:144)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.getStyle(Unknown Source)
    ... 132 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for Filter: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find function Add
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.ParseExecutor.visit(ParseExecutor.java:153)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.BindingWalker$BindingExecutionChain.execute(BindingWalker.java:218)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.BindingWalker.walk(BindingWalker.java:184)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.ElementHandlerImpl.endElement(ElementHandlerImpl.java:233)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.ParserHandler.endElement(ParserHandler.java:798)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:610)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1718)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2883)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:534)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1216)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:324)
    at org.geotools.xsd.Parser.parse(Parser.java:183)
    at org.geotools.xsd.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    at org.geoserver.catalog.SLDHandler.parse11(SLDHandler.java:207)
    ... 143 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find function Add
    at org.geotools.filter.FunctionFinder.findFunction(FunctionFinder.java:203)
    at org.geotools.filter.FunctionFinder.findFunction(FunctionFinder.java:147)
    at org.geotools.filter.FunctionFinder.findFunction(FunctionFinder.java:124)
    at org.geotools.xsd.filter.FilterParsingUtils.lookupExtendedOperator(FilterParsingUtils.java:169)
    at org.geotools.xsd.filter.FilterParsingUtils.parseExtendedOperators(FilterParsingUtils.java:135)
    at org.geotools.filter.v1_1.FilterTypeBinding.parse(FilterTypeBinding.java:100)
    at org.geotools.xsd.impl.ParseExecutor.visit(ParseExecutor.java:144)
    ... 162 more
```

Comment: what does your style say? Does the layer display? what versions of GeoServer and Java are you running? what is your operating system? and how did you install GeoServer?

Comment: It seems that there is function "Add" used somewhere in your SLD. Try to a) find it from your SLD and b) remove it. If that helps, think why the function was there and if it is really needed. I do not find Add from here https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html, but https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131002/using-simple-math-in-sld-file-on-geoserver suggests that GeoServer has supported that.

Comment: I use the <ogc:Add> in a lot of styles.  So difficult to tell which one as the log does not say any more.  I have tested on some of the styles using <ogc:Add> and they do work.