How to calculate attributes for SLD with GeoServer
When I use <ogc:Literal>5+5</ogc:Literal>, the calculation does not work. Is there a way to perform calculations in GeoServer SLD?

Try something like here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/131111/30184, but with ogc:Add.
